# Interface between 2 Sqlitedatabases for highavailability

Tags: sqlite

I wanted to know is there any interface between 2 Sqlite3 databases, like if one database gets updated other get updated automatically?? Please guide.

Comment: Having two databases on the same machine would not increase availability. You do want them to be distributed, don't you?

Comment: definitely, it will be different machines. initially i would like to test locally and then on different machines. if there are no such interfaces i would like to write one. can anybody please guide..

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation that is not an [appropriate use for SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

Different machines implies a client/server architecture, for which you should use an actual client/server database, not an embedded database like SQLite.
Many client/server databases already have built-in HA support.